# iptables jump targets - which terminate and which return?

Tags: linux, iptables

Where can I find documentation on which iptables jump targets terminate processing and which implicitly return.   For example "-j MARK" returns, but "-j DNAT" does not.

I can not find this documented anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any canonical documentation, and a quick DDG around didn't find anything.  In general, I find it's fairly straightforward to discern from context or purpose whether a target will be terminating or non-terminating (that's the official nomenclature; it may help you find docs in searches).